# Derivation of the $TT$ OPE?

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The operator product expansion (OPE) of the stress-energy tensor with itself in two-dimensional conformal field theory is:
$$T(z)T(w)\sim \frac{c/2}{(z-w)^4}+\frac{2}{(z-w)^2}T(w)+\frac{1}{z-w}\partial_wT(w)$$

In his [lecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028) on quantum field theory, Ginsparg stated that the $TT$ OPE can be obtained by "performing two conformal transformations in succession". I can't figure out how.

Also, some authors (e.g. [Qualls](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04074)) introduce the Virasoro algebra first, where the central charge $c$ already appears. Then the requirements that modes of the stress energy tensor, i.e. $L_n$, obey the Virasoro algebra leads to the $TT$ OPE. On the other hand, as far as I know, those lecture notes or books (like Ginsparg's lecture or the ["Yellow Book"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2256-9)) present the expression for the $TT$ OPE before discussing the Varasoro algebra, and simply state its validity without deriving it.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. How can one obtain the $TT$ OPE by performing two conformal transformations in succession?
2. From a physical point of view, which should come first, the $TT$ OPE or the Virasoro algebra?

Comment: It's impossible to argue which should come first. You choose your set of axioms to define a CFT, I choose mine. As long they are all consistent with each other, neither is more fundamental.

Comment: @Prahar But if I choose to present the Virasoro algebra after the $TT$ OPE, then where do these terms, e.g. the $(z-w)^{-4}$ term, come from?

Comment: you simply write down the most general TT OPE that is consistent with the axions of CFT. That includes a $(z-w)^{-4}$ term. Conformal invariance tells us that the coefficient of this term is an operator of dimension 0. Unitarity then tells us that this operator MUST be a number (i.e. proportional to the identity operator). Call this number $c/2$ and then proceed to derive the Virasoro algebra.